# Top Questions of the Week #18

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 18 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility suggested last week which I like is:

> **[How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)**
>
> Explains Environment Variables for
>   different Operating Systems in a
>   quick, dense, info-packed package.
>   (You don't have to go through an
>   entire 10-page article learning how
>   they work; just learn the relevant
>   stuff here.)

Comment: I just hit +1 for that.  I agree that this is helpful information, especially for people who run into the occasional program that depends on an environment variable being set a certain way (this is rare, but when it happens it usually effects those who are less technical).